# Zeep - invalid security for wsse password type

Tags: python, soap, zeep

We are using "BasicHTTPBinding WSS Type - PasswordText" authentication. I can successfully send the request manually using SoapUi tool, but in Zeep below code throws 500 internal server error and the response is

> An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
url = r'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Services/LoansIntegrationService.svc?singleWsdl'
client = Client(url ,wsse=UsernameToken('vvasu', 'demo'))
body = client.transport.load(r'.\wsdl\LoanRequest.wsdl') #fetch the updated wsdl file and pass it to request
result = client.transport.post(message=body, address=url, headers=headers)
print(result.content) #An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
```

Response:

````
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>```
````

Comment: `Client(url ,wsse=UsernameToken(r'<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>'))` looks like this is sample code where the real credentials should be substituted - though __NOT__ as plain text string literals ...

Comment: @holdenweb Edited the question with valid username and password. Still facing the same issue.